# A basic filter is returning an empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

```
def only_upper(t):
    res = []
    for s in t:
        if s.isupper():
            res.append(s)
        return res
t = ['a', 'B', 'c', 'D']

print only_upper(t)
```

I'm trying to figure out why this is returning an empty list. The result looks like this in the console:

```
[]
```

Comment: Try it on Python Tutor: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20only_upper%28t%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20res%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20s%20in%20t%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20s.isupper%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20res.append%28s%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20res%0A%0At%20%3D%20%5B'a',%20'B',%20'c',%20'D'%5D%0A%0Aprint%20only_upper%28t%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Comment: Closely look at the indentation of your `return` statement... it is inside the loop, hence will be called after first iteration already.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got an answer so quickly! I see my mistake now. List comprehensions come later in the textbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You return immediately after the first element of the `for` loop, instead of after it complete. Unindent your `return` statement and you should be fine:

```
def only_upper(t):
    res = []
    for s in t:
        if s.isupper():
            res.append(s)
    return res # Here!
```

Also worth mentioning that it's often easier to write filters like this in list-comprehensions instead of implementing the entire logic:

```
print([x for x in t if x.isupper()])
```

Answer (score 3):

As alternative to the above list comprehension is built-in `filter` function (in case it is even further in your book):

```
list(filter(lambda x: x.isupper(), ['a', 'B', 'c', 'D']))
```

Comment: Even simpler: `list(filter(str.isupper, ['a', 'B', 'c', 'D']))`.